# Using regular expresion in vscode to change some code

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I editing a latex document where I want to change the references from `\ref{eq:6.3.78}`  to `(\ref{eq:6.3.78})`

I tried to match first all the strings like `\ref{SOMETHING}` with `\ref{.\*}`
and then change to `(\ref{.\*})` but this don't work. Why? Or how can archive this.

Manually it would take me more than 10 hours since is a complete math book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape both the backslash and the curly braces.  Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \\ref\{[^}]+\}
Replace: ($0)
```

### Demo

If for some reason the above does not work with VSCode, then you may try explicitly capturing the entire pattern:

```
Find:    (\\ref\{[^}]+\})
Replace: ($1)
```

Note: If `$1` does not work, then try using `\\1` instead.

Comment: I had regular expresion desactived.